# What's the grammar and meaning of the sentence "We're make it example on that one!"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

The source of the sentence "We're make it example on that one!":

https://cnc.gamepedia.com/Twinblade

One of the unit's quote

Comment: It doesn't make any sense; I suspect it was written by someone with poor English skills. Maybe they were trying to say "We're making an example of that one."

Comment: Exactly! That's ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct English.

This is a programmed phrase used by a Russian Helicopter pilot in a computer game.
Either it is a mistake by the author of the game, or it is deliberate, to make it appear more "Russian". It probably means "We'll make an example of that one", meaning "We'll kill that person so others don't copy him"

Looking at the other phrases, there are some others that are unidiomatic "We go then!", "What shall it be?!!"

Comment: The canonical example of gamespeak [Engrish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engrish) is, of course, ['all your base are belong to us'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us).